# Exporting 3d map in format manageable by VRML Java viewer?

Tags: qgis, 3d, viewer

I am new to GIS.

I am working on a mapping project for scuba diving sites, and I need to create 3d maps viewable by users on android tablets, iOS, websites, etc...

So far, I achieved the map result I expected using [GoldenSoftware](http://www.goldensoftware.com/) "Didger+surfer".

The problem now is to eport the 3d map in a format manageable by a vrml java viewer.

Is there a way to do this using QGIS?

Comment: You can check QGIS goes 3D with the OsgEarth Globe Plugin (http://underdark.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/qgis-goes-3d-with-the-osgearth-plugin/)